# Does any working sample code exist for WiFi-Direct on Android?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

The documentation for Wifi Direct on the android developer site includes scraps of code taken from a now defunct [sample application](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/) (Android Studio baulks at the project structure) that I managed to find a [modified github version](https://github.com/changfeng1050/WiFiDirectDemo) implemented in Kotlin that builds and runs however testing between two devices (Galaxy S8+: Android 10, Oppo Reno4: Android 12) failed to achieve anything useful (could not create a group or locate a peer on either device).

All SO discussions on the topic seem to be over a decade old so I'm left asking if the functionality does work anymore or if it has just rotted away on the Android source tree, is anybody able to direct me to some functional code or at least confirm the feature still works in later versions of the operating system? [or would I be better off explicitly configuring the devices using the hotspot feature?]

Comment: What do you wanna do with wifi direct? If both devices are on the same wifi apps on the devices can communicate with each other. If there is no wifi you can make one of the devices a hotspot. Then the same apps can communicate again. But what is it that you wanna do?

Comment: My project involves making a camera swarm using multiple phones and tablets and merging the different camera angles of the scene; I had hoped to make it completely p2p with all nodes sharing the processing (until I found out that Wifi-Direct insists on a consistant  Group Owner - so will have to settle for a master node) but after spending a day and a half trying to get Wifi-Direct running, ill take what I can get at the moment to get connectivity running so I can move on to the meat of the problem.

Comment: Sorry, interesting, but i did not ask for that info. It was more why you thought you needed to use wif-direct instead of just wifi or one device being the hotspot.

Comment: Make a group owner and connect peers to it bypassing the need for configuring network access on each device.. But I assumed that would have been implicit.

Comment: Ok. Never got that far with wifi-direct ... But if you use one device as hotspot there is nothing to configure on a client once the client device connected to the hotspot. Well... i dont know what you want to configure ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the example app referred to (https://github.com/changfeng1050/WiFiDirectDemo) by adding the following to the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <!-- If your app derives location information from Wi-Fi APIs,
    android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"
         don't include the "usesPermissionFlags" attribute. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NEARBY_WIFI_DEVICES"
     />

    <!-- If any feature in your app relies on precise location information,
         don't include the "maxSdkVersion" attribute. -->
    <uses-permission
            android:required="true"
            android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
    android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
```

https://github.com/realityexpander/WiFiDirectDemo